# Potentiometer wiring

Tags: potentiometer

We currently have a potentiometer that is connected to Allen Bradley 22a-d2p3n104 to regulate speed of a motor (A).

I would like to keep that connection but also need to connect the potentiometer to a PLC which controls an air solenoid that will open or close depending on the speed of motor (A).

That is, if the speed is at 100% then open the solenoid every 3 minutes, at 50% open every 2 minutes, and at 0 don't open the solenoid and so on.

How do I connect the pot? It only has three wires. Do I splice the output and connect one wire to the PLC and one to Allen Bradley VFD?

Comment: You can have one master speed control input but multiple motors need separate drivers and tach feedback sensors

Comment: I updated the question to better get an idea of what we are trying to do.  We have a Click PLC and need to open an Air Solenoid depending on the speed of the motor (a)

Comment: Thresholds need tolerances but also 2 independent ESC motor controllers

Comment: That isn't enough detail. What about all the other %'s in between.  No this won't work, without PLC and AB specs

Comment: Bring the analog signal (potentiometer) into the PLC on an Analog Input, then output via Analog Output the speed to the motor, and via Digital Output to the solenoid?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to get a ganged potentiometer, this gives you two completely isolated but mechanical connected potentiometers. You can also match the resistance to the PLC and ESC.